# Understanding C backtraces in error logs

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I've recently started writing C programs to parse and analyze a massive data stream in real-time. One thing I'm having trouble understanding, is (a) error stack traces, and (b) their usefulness in debugging problems. Anyways, I'm hoping someone can help me mentally parse what I see here, or at least to have some idea of what it means, or if I should even bother trying to understand. I really want to find out why the program is crashing randomly.

```
*** Error in `/home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000242a8b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f5c695227e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f5c6952b37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f5c6952f53c]
/home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program[0x401e8c]
/home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program[0x4020c3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f5c694cb830]
/home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program[0x401329]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1051590                            /home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 1051590                            /home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 1051590                            /home/user_name/project_folder/the_program/the_program
023e7000-02438000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f5c54000000-7f5c54021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c54021000-7f5c58000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c5c000000-7f5c5c0b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c5c0b1000-7f5c60000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c622d2000-7f5c622dd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7f5c622dd000-7f5c624dc000 ---p 0000b000 ca:01 395465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7f5c624dc000-7f5c624dd000 r--p 0000a000 ca:01 395465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7f5c624dd000-7f5c624de000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 395465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7f5c624de000-7f5c624e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c624e4000-7f5c624ef000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7f5c624ef000-7f5c626ee000 ---p 0000b000 ca:01 395468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7f5c626ee000-7f5c626ef000 r--p 0000a000 ca:01 395468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7f5c626ef000-7f5c626f0000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 395468                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7f5c626f0000-7f5c62706000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395461                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f5c62706000-7f5c62905000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 395461                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f5c62905000-7f5c62906000 r--p 00015000 ca:01 395461                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f5c62906000-7f5c62907000 rw-p 00016000 ca:01 395461                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f5c62907000-7f5c62909000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c62909000-7f5c62911000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7f5c62911000-7f5c62b10000 ---p 00008000 ca:01 395474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7f5c62b10000-7f5c62b11000 r--p 00007000 ca:01 395474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7f5c62b11000-7f5c62b12000 rw-p 00008000 ca:01 395474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7f5c62b12000-7f5c62b13000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c62b13000-7f5c63313000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c63313000-7f5c63314000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c63314000-7f5c63b14000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c63b14000-7f5c63b1b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5289                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f5c63b1b000-7f5c63d1a000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 5289                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f5c63d1a000-7f5c63d1b000 r--p 00006000 ca:01 5289                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f5c63d1b000-7f5c63d1c000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 5289                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f5c63d1c000-7f5c63d25000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395466                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f5c63d25000-7f5c63f24000 ---p 00009000 ca:01 395466                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f5c63f24000-7f5c63f25000 r--p 00008000 ca:01 395466                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f5c63f25000-7f5c63f26000 rw-p 00009000 ca:01 395466                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f5c63f26000-7f5c63f54000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c63f54000-7f5c64023000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5360                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f5c64023000-7f5c64223000 ---p 000cf000 ca:01 5360                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f5c64223000-7f5c64226000 r--p 000cf000 ca:01 5360                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f5c64226000-7f5c64228000 rw-p 000d2000 ca:01 5360                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f5c64228000-7f5c64229000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c64229000-7f5c64270000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4236                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f5c64270000-7f5c6446f000 ---p 00047000 ca:01 4236                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f5c6446f000-7f5c64471000 r--p 00046000 ca:01 4236                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f5c64471000-7f5c64473000 rw-p 00048000 ca:01 4236                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f5c64473000-7f5c64474000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c64474000-7f5c64482000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f5c64482000-7f5c64681000 ---p 0000e000 ca:01 4177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f5c64681000-7f5c64682000 r--p 0000d000 ca:01 4177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f5c64682000-7f5c64683000 rw-p 0000e000 ca:01 4177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f5c64683000-7f5c646aa000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4178                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f5c646aa000-7f5c648aa000 ---p 00027000 ca:01 4178                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f5c648aa000-7f5c648ab000 r--p 00027000 ca:01 4178                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f5c648ab000-7f5c648ac000 rw-p 00028000 ca:01 4178                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f5c648ac000-7f5c64922000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 333                        /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f5c64922000-7f5c64b21000 ---p 00076000 ca:01 333                        /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f5c64b21000-7f5c64b22000 r--p 00075000 ca:01 333                        /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f5c64b22000-7f5c64b23000 rw-p 00076000 ca:01 333                        /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f5c64b23000-7f5c64b55000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 600                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f5c64b55000-7f5c64d54000 ---p 00032000 ca:01 600                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f5c64d54000-7f5c64d55000 r--p 00031000 ca:01 600                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f5c64d55000-7f5c64d56000 rw-p 00032000 ca:01 600                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f5c64d56000-7f5c64d8a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f5c64d8a000-7f5c64f89000 ---p 00034000 ca:01 1177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f5c64f89000-7f5c64f8b000 r--p 00033000 ca:01 1177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f5c64f8b000-7f5c64f8c000 rw-p 00035000 ca:01 1177                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f5c64f8c000-7f5c64f9d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 12275                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f5c64f9d000-7f5c6519d000 ---p 00011000 ca:01 12275                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f5c6519d000-7f5c6519e000 r--p 00011000 ca:01 12275                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f5c6519e000-7f5c6519f000 rw-p 00012000 ca:01 12275                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f5c6519f000-7f5c651d0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 27656                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f5c651d0000-7f5c653d0000 ---p 00031000 ca:01 27656                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f5c653d0000-7f5c653d1000 r--p 00031000 ca:01 27656                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f5c653d1000-7f5c653d2000 rw-p 00032000 ca:01 27656                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f5c653d2000-7f5c6542c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5344                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f5c6542c000-7f5c6562b000 ---p 0005a000 ca:01 5344                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f5c6562b000-7f5c65635000 r--p 00059000 ca:01 5344                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f5c65635000-7f5c65637000 rw-p 00063000 ca:01 5344                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f5c65637000-7f5c65650000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396860                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f5c65650000-7f5c6584f000 ---p 00019000 ca:01 396860                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f5c6584f000-7f5c65850000 r--p 00018000 ca:01 396860                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f5c65850000-7f5c65851000 rw-p 00019000 ca:01 396860                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f5c65851000-7f5c65866000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5740                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f5c65866000-7f5c65a65000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 5740                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f5c65a65000-7f5c65a66000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 5740                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f5c65a66000-7f5c65a67000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 5740                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f5c65a67000-7f5c65a97000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4139                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f5c65a97000-7f5c65c97000 ---p 00030000 ca:01 4139                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f5c65c97000-7f5c65c98000 r--p 00030000 ca:01 4139                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f5c65c98000-7f5c65c99000 rw-p 00031000 ca:01 4139                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f5c65c99000-7f5c65c9a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c65c9a000-7f5c65d39000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4227                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f5c65d39000-7f5c65f38000 ---p 0009f000 ca:01 4227                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f5c65f38000-7f5c65f39000 r--p 0009e000 ca:01 4227                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f5c65f39000-7f5c65f3c000 rw-p 0009f000 ca:01 4227                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f5c65f3c000-7f5c65fc0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4181                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f5c65fc0000-7f5c661bf000 ---p 00084000 ca:01 4181                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f5c661bf000-7f5c661c2000 r--p 00083000 ca:01 4181                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f5c661c2000-7f5c661c5000 rw-p 00086000 ca:01 4181                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f5c661c5000-7f5c661c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c661c6000-7f5c661ce000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4196                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f5c661ce000-7f5c663cd000 ---p 00008000 ca:01 4196                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f5c663cd000-7f5c663ce000 r--p 00007000 ca:01 4196                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f5c663ce000-7f5c663cf000 rw-p 00008000 ca:01 4196                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f5c663cf000-7f5c663d2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396800                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5c663d2000-7f5c665d1000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 396800                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5c665d1000-7f5c665d2000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 396800                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5c665d2000-7f5c665d3000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 396800                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5c665d3000-7f5c666f6000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 595                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f5c666f6000-7f5c668f5000 ---p 00123000 ca:01 595                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f5c668f5000-7f5c66900000 r--p 00122000 ca:01 595                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f5c66900000-7f5c66902000 rw-p 0012d000 ca:01 595                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f5c66902000-7f5c66903000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c66903000-7f5c66940000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4179                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f5c66940000-7f5c66b40000 ---p 0003d000 ca:01 4179                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f5c66b40000-7f5c66b41000 r--p 0003d000 ca:01 4179                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f5c66b41000-7f5c66b43000 rw-p 0003e000 ca:01 4179                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f5c66b43000-7f5c66b44000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c66b44000-7f5c66b5d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5357                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f5c66b5d000-7f5c66d5d000 ---p 00019000 ca:01 5357                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f5c66d5d000-7f5c66d5e000 r--p 00019000 ca:01 5357                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f5c66d5e000-7f5c66d5f000 rw-p 0001a000 ca:01 5357                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f5c66d5f000-7f5c66d76000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395476                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f5c66d76000-7f5c66f76000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 395476                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f5c66f76000-7f5c66f77000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 395476                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f5c66f77000-7f5c66f78000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 395476                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f5c66f78000-7f5c66f7a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c66f7a000-7f5c66f87000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 12285                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c66f87000-7f5c67187000 ---p 0000d000 ca:01 12285                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67187000-7f5c67188000 r--p 0000d000 ca:01 12285                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67188000-7f5c67189000 rw-p 0000e000 ca:01 12285                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67189000-7f5c67193000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5328                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5c67193000-7f5c67392000 ---p 0000a000 ca:01 5328                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5c67392000-7f5c67393000 r--p 00009000 ca:01 5328                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5c67393000-7f5c67394000 rw-p 0000a000 ca:01 5328                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5c67394000-7f5c67397000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5c67397000-7f5c67596000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 396774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5c67596000-7f5c67597000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 396774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5c67597000-7f5c67598000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 396774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5c67598000-7f5c675c4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5325                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5c675c4000-7f5c677c3000 ---p 0002c000 ca:01 5325                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5c677c3000-7f5c677c5000 r--p 0002b000 ca:01 5325                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5c677c5000-7f5c677c6000 rw-p 0002d000 ca:01 5325                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5c677c6000-7f5c677c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c677c7000-7f5c6788a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5327                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5c6788a000-7f5c67a8a000 ---p 000c3000 ca:01 5327                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5c67a8a000-7f5c67a97000 r--p 000c3000 ca:01 5327                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5c67a97000-7f5c67a99000 rw-p 000d0000 ca:01 5327                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5c67a99000-7f5c67a9c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395473                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f5c67a9c000-7f5c67c9b000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 395473                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f5c67c9b000-7f5c67c9c000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 395473                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f5c67c9c000-7f5c67c9d000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 395473                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f5c67c9d000-7f5c67cea000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 704                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67cea000-7f5c67ee9000 ---p 0004d000 ca:01 704                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67ee9000-7f5c67eeb000 r--p 0004c000 ca:01 704                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67eeb000-7f5c67eec000 rw-p 0004e000 ca:01 704                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f5c67eec000-7f5c67eee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c67eee000-7f5c67f35000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 5305                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5c67f35000-7f5c68134000 ---p 00047000 ca:01 5305                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5c68134000-7f5c68136000 r--p 00046000 ca:01 5305                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5c68136000-7f5c68138000 rw-p 00048000 ca:01 5305                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5c68138000-7f5c68352000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395917                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f5c68352000-7f5c68551000 ---p 0021a000 ca:01 395917                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f5c68551000-7f5c6856d000 r--p 00219000 ca:01 395917                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f5c6856d000-7f5c68579000 rw-p 00235000 ca:01 395917                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f5c68579000-7f5c6857c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c6857c000-7f5c685da000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395918                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f5c685da000-7f5c687da000 ---p 0005e000 ca:01 395918                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f5c687da000-7f5c687de000 r--p 0005e000 ca:01 395918                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f5c687de000-7f5c687e5000 rw-p 00062000 ca:01 395918                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f5c687e5000-7f5c687fb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396789                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5c687fb000-7f5c689fa000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 396789                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5c689fa000-7f5c689fb000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 396789                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5c689fb000-7f5c68b03000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f5c68b03000-7f5c68d02000 ---p 00108000 ca:01 395479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f5c68d02000-7f5c68d03000 r--p 00107000 ca:01 395479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f5c68d03000-7f5c68d04000 rw-p 00108000 ca:01 395479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f5c68d04000-7f5c68e76000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 28090                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f5c68e76000-7f5c69076000 ---p 00172000 ca:01 28090                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f5c69076000-7f5c69080000 r--p 00172000 ca:01 28090                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f5c69080000-7f5c69082000 rw-p 0017c000 ca:01 28090                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f5c69082000-7f5c69086000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c69086000-7f5c6909e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395467                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f5c6909e000-7f5c6929d000 ---p 00018000 ca:01 395467                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f5c6929d000-7f5c6929e000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 395467                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f5c6929e000-7f5c6929f000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 395467                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f5c6929f000-7f5c692a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c692a3000-7f5c692aa000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395470                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f5c692aa000-7f5c694a9000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 395470                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f5c694a9000-7f5c694aa000 r--p 00006000 ca:01 395470                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f5c694aa000-7f5c694ab000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 395470                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f5c694ab000-7f5c6966b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f5c6966b000-7f5c6986b000 ---p 001c0000 ca:01 395484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f5c6986b000-7f5c6986f000 r--p 001c0000 ca:01 395484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f5c6986f000-7f5c69871000 rw-p 001c4000 ca:01 395484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f5c69871000-7f5c69875000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c69875000-7f5c698a2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 8152                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.9
7f5c698a2000-7f5c69aa1000 ---p 0002d000 ca:01 8152                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.9
7f5c69aa1000-7f5c69aa4000 r--p 0002c000 ca:01 8152                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.9
7f5c69aa4000-7f5c69aa5000 rw-p 0002f000 ca:01 8152                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.9
7f5c69aa5000-7f5c69b23000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 46107                      /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.0
7f5c69b23000-7f5c69d23000 ---p 0007e000 ca:01 46107                      /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.0
7f5c69d23000-7f5c69d28000 r--p 0007e000 ca:01 46107                      /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.0
7f5c69d28000-7f5c69d29000 rw-p 00083000 ca:01 46107                      /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.0
7f5c69d29000-7f5c69d4f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395462                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f5c69f2c000-7f5c69f41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c69f4b000-7f5c69f4e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5c69f4e000-7f5c69f4f000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 395462                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f5c69f4f000-7f5c69f50000 rw-p 00026000 ca:01 395462                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f5c69f50000-7f5c69f51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffc90bb9000-7ffc90bda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc90bf4000-7ffc90bf6000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc90bf6000-7ffc90bf8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: *... find out why the program is crashing randomly* `double free or corruption (!prev):`

Comment: It would be much easier to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find out where you're double-freeing the memory.

Comment: The numbers become more useful when you enable or install debugging info.